# `read -t` is not printing my input

Tags: command-line

I use the following command:

```
read -t 5 num
```

However, running:

```
echo "$num"
```

is not printing the value of `num`.

Comment: It works for me - which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Do you key-in some input and press Enter within 5 seconds after running `read -t 5 num` or you just wait for it to time-out?

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for `read` is demonstrated by this example:

```
$ read num
10 
$ echo "$num"
10
```

Answer (score 0):

`read` is a [Bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) function that reads a line from standard input and stores it to a variable. The basic syntax of `read` is:

```
read var
```

If you run this, the prompt will wait for you to enter text until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the text will be saved to the `var` variable, which you can then display using `echo`:

```
echo $var
```

The `-t` flag you use in your question, is used to make `read` time out after the specified time (in seconds) has passed. If the specified amount of time has passed and you haven't entered text and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `echo $var` will return nothing.

You have probably misunderstood what happens if you just type text while `read` waits for input, perhaps thinking that the text you typed will be used as input when `read` times out, thus it would be stored in the `var` variable.

But this is not the case! The text will only be stored in `var` if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.